# Regular Expression Validator does not validate empty textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

I would like to validate the textbox for specific text and it must not be blank.  But the regular expression validator is not validating if the text box is **BLANK**.  However, it validates if I type something in the text box.

How can I make regular expression to trigger even if the text box is empty?

Should I use Required Validator + Regex Validator at the same time?  Thanks.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcard" runat="server" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtcard" ErrorMessage="Please type credit card no" 
ValidationExpression="^\d{16}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally do as you suggest and have a required validator as well. This would allow you to have a different message for each rule.

Another option that I would recommend any web developer look at is the JQuery validation plugin. If you combine this with Fluent Validation, you can keep all of your validation rules for your business objects in one place and you can validate on the Client side and at the Server using those same rules.

[JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

[Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 6):

You should combine your `RegularExpressionValidator` with a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

If either fails it will block due to validation firing.  Each one serves a purpose and the `RegularExpressionValidator`'s purpose is to validate entered text not the lack of text.

If you want to do it all in one validator your could use the `CustomValidator` and set `ValidateEmptyText='true'`.  Then you could use the javascript regex to do the checking.  I would recommend the two validators though as this is a standard approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should use both at the same time. Not returning a Validation error if the Value is blank is common with the ASP.NET validation controls. You will see the same behavior from the Validation attributes in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Comment: +1. You can get around this with a custom DataAnnotationValidator.  I wrote one, but it requires inheriting from a base object. It's very useful: http://bit.ly/bcwher  It allows you to add any number of ValidationAttributes to properties and displays the first error message that causes validation to fail (as multiple asp validators would)